# Is the MKS GEN V1.2 compatible with Arduino IDE as Arduino MEGA Board?

Tags: arduino-mega

I need to do a Servo controller using Arduino and I have a spare MKS GEN V1.2 board right now, looking at the documentation from here http://reprap.org/wiki/MKS_GEN it seems this board is actually an Arduino board which can be programmed with the Arduino IDE.

Is this a correct observation that the MKS GEN V1.2 board is, in fact, a Arduino MEGA board internally?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It features an onboard ATmega2560.

This means that it is *internally* compatible with the Arduino Mega 2560. This does not mean that it is *completely* compatible with such since of course there is no way to use Mega shields with the board. This also means that there may be a core that provides *better* facility with the board, supporting its connections (LCD, positioning, heater/fan, etc.) better than the generic Mega core would.

Comment: This is good news for me, we can reprogram it to use our own Arduino codes to control the servo motors based on our code, the problem now is there seems no Schematic for the board so we start using it as our Arduino board

Comment: Did you see the third image in the Summary section?

Comment: Ah yes I can see it now, so for example the `D30` there in the diagram corresponds to Arduino D30 pin?