# MKS GEN board pinouts for Arduino MEGA

Tags: arduino-mega

As per this SO:

[Is the MKS GEN V1.2 compatible with Arduino IDE as Arduino MEGA Board?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/31533/is-the-mks-gen-v1-2-compatible-with-arduino-ide-as-arduino-mega-board)

the MKS GEN board is an Arduino MEGA board mixed with other circuits.

My questions is how does it correlate with the Arduino Mega Board pinouts, especially the ones encircled in red below:

[image]

E.g. for connector `Jc_M2` where does the `EN`, `STEP` and `DIR` pins connect to the ATmega2560 controller? And also for the other servo controller pins.